# gitlab-ci-runner choose executer "Please enter the executor:"

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have ran `gitlab-ci-multi-runner` in a container by docker.

When I execute the `gitlab-ci-multi-runner register` in the container,it ask

> Please enter the executor: docker...?

If I choose `docker`,does it mean a docker container will run on the current container?

Sorry for my poor english :)

Answer (score 10):

By choosing 'docker' as the CI runner executor a docker container will be created to run the builds. If you are unsure about which executor to use the 'shell' executor is probably your best choice. [gitlab-ci-multi-runner configuration](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md) documentation has more information on how to configure the various executors.

Comment: but the `runner` was installed in the docker container,how to create container in container?

Comment: Yes, if you are running the runner in Docker and choose the 'docker' executor it will try to run a container inside the container. If that's not what you want, choose 'shell' executor.